# Way to export and import TIFF file symbols

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, style

I've read several reference to import saved 'style reference' for shapefile but couldn't find same works for TIFF files (or any image files).

I'm user of ArcGIS 10.3.1 and now I have TIFF files that have almost 20 category symbols (which `L2_CODE` in the picture below). And I want to save these symbols and apply to other TIFF files. I've already tried saving as .ri f(style reference), but this file doesn't show up when apply to new TIFF file
[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to use a style reference for TIFF file,
or is it impossible in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an export/import option for the symbology that has been applied to a raster layer; therefore, the same symbology cannot be easily applied to other rasters.

Workaround:-

1. You can save the raster with the desired symbology to a Layer file using the Save As Layer File option
2. Use the Set Data Source button in the layer’s Properties Source tab to change the source for the Layer to a different raster dataset
3. The layer will then appear with the same symbology as the original
4. Repeat this process as necessary

It can be easily accomplished in ArcGIS Pro, using the geoprocessing tools.
Kindly follow  [Apply the same symbology to multiple rasters in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000022636) for a better understanding.

I have another documentation that you can follow [Apply the same symbology to multiple rasters in ArcMap](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000014408).